# WPF Changing the orientation of a listview including its content

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, orientation

Suggest you have a ListView, which contains a lot of complex controls (let's say: each ListViewItem is a Grid of StackPanels of userControls...).

The question is :

> How can we bind all this content orientation to the orientation of the
>   ListView ?? Could going from Horizontal ListView to Vertical ListView
>   change also the orientation of the content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change orientation just apply a transformation on the ListView like this:

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
        </ListView.LayoutTransform>
        <ListViewItem>George</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem IsSelected="True">Fred</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Andrea</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```